# How I know the signature of a signed url?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a lambda which generates a signed URL for users to upload files to s3 bucket. The code is in nodejs:

```
export const getSignedURL = async (): Promise<{ signedURL: string }> => {
  try {
    const s3 = new S3();
    const params = {
      Bucket: CONFIG.s3Bucket,
      Key: `${CONFIG.s3PictureFolder}/${uuidv4()}`,
      Expires: CONFIG.presignedURLExpires,
    };
    const signedURL = await s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params);
    console.log(`generate signedURL url: ${signedURL}`);
    return { signedURL };
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    throw err;
  }
};
```

I am able to get the url success. However, when I test it via `curl`:

```
curl -XPUT PRESIGNED_URL --data "my data"
```

I got this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>XXXX</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>
```

It seems that this URL requires an access key. Does this key mean AWS credential key which is issued by `IAM`?

This URL was generated by the lambda function. How do I know which key it uses? And I'd like to generate a public presigned url for users to upload. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Can you show us what the signed URL looks like? (Feel free to modify it to hide personal information.) It should contain all the necessary information.

Comment: No, your AWS credential is used when generating the URL, but once created, the URL is 'public' - it could be used by anyone with no additional keys. There's a few possible causes but the most likely is a simple formatting/encoding issue in the bucket or key values.

Answer (score 0):

After come debugging, I found that I need to add `Content-Type` when generate the presigned URL like below:

```
const params = {
      Bucket: CONFIG.s3Bucket,
      Key: `${CONFIG.s3PictureFolder}/${uuidv4()}`,
      Expires: CONFIG.presignedURLExpires,
      ContentType: 'text/plain'
    };
```